# How should I implement an "object viewer/visualizer"?

Tags: java, user-interface, serialization, viewer

As one of the features in an in-house testing tool I'm interested in allowing the user to view the fileds' values of Java objects in a graphical way.
So, as far as I understand, the object's class needs to implement Serializable -and according to Effective Java book, preferably the custom form of the read/write methods.

This way I can use the serialized version of the objects as input for the viewer (this is more for after-run comparisons and regression-type comparisons with other runs rather than run-time viewing)

1. How does one go about implementing
   something like this,especially as I
   have close to zero experience in
   developing Java GUI applications?
2. Are there any relevant frameworks
   available-both for GUI as well as
   for the object-visualization part?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for years and it's performance has been great both in flexibility and speed.

But, if you're going web, then something like Tapestry 5's bean components ([BeanDisplay](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/tapestry-core/ref/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/BeanDisplay.html), [BeanEditForm](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/tapestry-core/ref/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/BeanEditForm.html) and friends) are definitely worth a quick prototype these has been very good friends also.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would use XMLEncoder (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)

2) I would try to use something similar to UML (as it is a well understood standard

However, does it have to be in Java GUI? If this was a web-application, then using the XML outputter, you could use some reasonably simple XML Stylesheets (XSL) over the XML to produce the output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! RE:UML - you mean as display "idea"?  But isn't UML more for class diagrams etc rather than single objects, where the values are the main focus?

Comment: It can be a web app I guess - if it can be VERY easily installed (given that  I've not much of a backgrounds in this area as well..)

Comment: UML is for Class diagrams, but you can just display the attributes, and their values. If you prefer not to use UML, then a simple tree structure may work as well (this is kind of what you would see in a debug tool to show attribute values).